# OpenCV incompatibility issues

Tags: python, opencv, conda

I'm trying to install the opencv package via `conda install opencv` and get the message

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \ 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                          

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - opencv -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']

Your python: python=3.8

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
```

How can I solve that issues so I can use the package?

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
conda update navigator-updater
conda install opencv-python
```

Comment: Can you explain what was the cause? I can't understand the regex expression in the "Specifications" section.

Comment: @kallikles did it work? In local python, in order to pip opencv you should use pip install opencv-python, so analogously for conda. https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/ opencv-python is the official name of the package